# how can i create a fire using Ignition Gazebo

Tags: sensors, sdformat, gazebo-model, gazebo-ignition, ignition-fortress

i am trying to create a Fire in our world .we want a real fire it could be detected by thermal camera and also other sensors. I used particle emitter to create fire.But the thermal camera couldn’t detect the the particles.Is there any other options to create fire in Ignition?

Comment: a thermal camera detect heat, not particles

Comment: if the particles have temperature properties how can i detect the thermal properties of particles?